# TabControl losing selected tab on Window.Show

Tags: wpf, selection, tabcontrol, reset, show-hide

We have an MVVM (Cinch) solution that has a Window with a TabControl in it.  The ItemsSource is bound to a CollectionView (DefaultView generated from an ObservableCollection), with IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=true.  Everything works great the first time the Window loads... tabs are displaying correctly and the user can switch between them.

The problem occurs when the Window is hidden and shown again.  The first tab is always selected again, regardless of what the CurrentItem in the CollectionView is.  The line before the .Show has the CurrentItem as the tab we want, but the tab switches during the .Show operation.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: I justed tested this with the demo project and I can't reproduce this.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18919663/mvvmbug.png

2 buttons, 1 hides, 1 shows window, the window has a tab view, the tab remains unchanged between hides and shows.

It would reset if you are reinitializing the second Window on each call. (i.e. Windows2 myWin = new Window2(); myWin.Show();)

Comment: If you are just calling .Show and .Hide, I don't see why you would see an issue, if you are making a new instance for each show, then that's your issue.

Comment: The window and its VM are retained throughout the life of the application, so I'm thinking it has to do with the MEFedMVVM/Cinch framework.

Comment: After some more testing, I found that the issue was with focus being maintained on the tab when the window was closed.  To fix it, I set focus to a control outside the tab control whenever the selected tab was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a hack. But you could override the Activated event and store the tab index before it gets reset and set it again when it reactivates.

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
{
    int tabControlIndex = myTabController.SelectedIndex;
    base.OnActivated(e);
    myTabController.SelectedIndex = tabControlIndex ;
}
```